# Print stack trace with line numbers

Tags: c#, .net

I am printing the current stack trace like

```
Console.WriteLine(new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace());
```

But this just shows the current call stack and doesn't show which lines of each file/method are responsible for calling the next function.

How do I print a stack trace that looks just like the stack trace that gets printed by default on a crash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass `true` to the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_StackTrace__ctor_System_Boolean_) to instruct it to capture file/line information.

Alternatively, use `Environment.StackTrace`, if you just need the textual representation of the stack trace.

Additionally, the matching `.pdb` file must be in the expected location (usually next to the binary).